# SSIS - How to parse multilevel xml into a different SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

Can you please help me with this? I have thousands of xml files like this:

```
<eolresult>
<eolpresetting>
<datetime>04.06.2021 15:26:20</datetime>
<order id="3I6LAKPVSLXSK316_FLX101xxxxxxxxxxxxxx000SK35X3PN9P40006C24A4NORL0L7P1XVV0008I96T24D3ZZF0006A0LTS0000"/>
</eolpresetting>
<testresult>IO</testresult>
<results>
<!-- PRN="3I6LAKPVSLXSK316_FLX101xxxxxxxxxxxxxx000SK35X3PN9P40006C24A4NORL0L7P1XVV0008I96T24D3ZZF0006A0LTS0000" -->
<test name="Airbag SAB">
<value name="Measured value - Generator">2,151977</value>
<value name="Low limit - Generator">1,74</value>
<value name="High limit - Generator">2,46</value>
<value name="Measured value - Break contact 1">5,079372</value>
<value name="Minumum value - Break contact 1">1,73</value>
<value name="Measured value - Break contact 2">5,104009</value>
<value name="Minumum value - Break contact 2">1,73</value>
<value name="Test OK">True</value>
</test>
<test name="Airbag CAB">
<value name="Measured value - Generator">2,131677</value>
<value name="Low limit - Generator">1,74</value>
<value name="High limit - Generator">2,26</value>
<value name="Measured value - Break contact 1">5,061298</value>
<value name="Minumum value - Break contact 1">1,73</value>
<value name="Measured value - Break contact 2">5,094279</value>
<value name="Minumum value - Break contact 2">1,73</value>
<value name="Test OK">True</value>
</test>
<test name="Heating">
<value name="Measured value">1,34909</value>
<value name="Low limit">1,22</value>
<value name="High limit">1,72</value>
<value name="Test OK">True</value>
</test>
<test name="SBR">
<value name="Measured value - Low force">399,8799</value>
<value name="Low limit - Low force">332</value>
<value name="High limit - Low force">468</value>
<value name="Measured value - Low force - Force [kg]">5,176686</value>
<value name="Low limit - Low force - Force [kg]">5,1</value>
<value name="High limit - Low force - Force [kg]">6,4</value>
<value name="Regulator Active - Low force">True</value>
<value name="Measured value - High force">100,0365</value>
<value name="Low limit - High force">83</value>
<value name="High limit - High force">117</value>
<value name="Measured value - High force - Force [kg]">33,72532</value>
<value name="Low limit - High force - Force [kg]">33,6</value>
<value name="High limit - High force - Force [kg]">34,3</value>
<value name="Regulator Active - High force">True</value>
<value name="Strain Gauge - Tare [kg]">-10,68025</value>
<value name="Test OK">True</value>
</test>
<test name="Headrests">
<value name="Force - Measured">16,61965</value>
<value name="Force - Low Limit">15,81</value>
<value name="Force - High Limit">17,64</value>
<value name="Regulator Active">True</value>
<value name="Strain Gauge - Tare [kg]">-8,725739E-02</value>
<value name="Test OK">True</value>
</results>
</eolresult>
```

And I would like to import this data into a SQL Server database into separate tables, defined by the "test name" which every tables should contain `order id`.

I tried to follow some guides on the internet but without success.

Thank you so much

Comment: You won't be able to use any of SQL Server's built-in XML functions for this unless you have valid XML to use. Your example XML is missing some closing tags.

Comment: As @AlwaysLearning already pointed out, you have to have a well-formed XML. You may need to create and run XSLT Transformation first to make XML digestible to SSIS.